# Outlook Synchronization - Outlook 2010 and SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization, outlook, task

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and I want outlook to reflect whatever tasks I create/update/delete in my SharePoint site. How can I synchronize tasks from SharePoint to Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the tasks list and click on the "Connect to Outlook" button in the list ribbon. This will open your outlook and connect the task list.
Every update you make in Sharepoint will be reflected in Outlook and viceversa.
You can work with Outlook in offline mode and synchronize tasks when you go back online.